# How do I run cron-like job at certain date time in the future using Agenda in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, agenda

I have a problem here. How do i run job at certain date time in the future using Agenda like node-scheduler do. Based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule, node-schedule have cron-style scheduling method. So it is easier for me to extract date from my input. I have read Agenda documentation https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda#agenda-events, it says Agenda uses Human Interval for specifying the intervals.

[image: Cron]

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a future date, you can convert this to number of `days` from today or even number of `seconds` as below and then use the same with `agenda` cron job

```js
function findDaysDifference ( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var oneDay_ms = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
    
  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms/oneDay_ms); 
}

var futureDate = new Date(2018, 0, 1);
var daysFromNow = findDaysDifference(new Date(), futureDate);

console.log(daysFromNow);
```

Then create `agenda` job and schedule it with `daysFromNow` calculated above,

```
agenda.define('sayHello', function(job) {
  console.log("Hello!");
});

// Schedule a job to run once at a given time
agenda.schedule(daysFromNow + ' days', 'sayHello');
```

If you want to schedule it at particular time in the future, you can calculate the seconds as below,

```js
function findSecondsDifference ( date1, date2 ) { 
      var oneSecond_ms = 1000;
  
      // Convert both dates to milliseconds
      var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
      var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

      // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
      var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
        
      // Convert back to days and return
      return Math.round(difference_ms/oneSecond_ms); 
    }

    var futureDate = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 16);
    var secsFromNow = findSecondsDifference(new Date(), futureDate);

    console.log(secsFromNow);
```

Then create `agenda` job and schedule it with `secsFromNow` calculated above,

```
agenda.define('sayHello', function(job) {
  console.log("Hello!");
});

// Schedule a job to run once at a given time
agenda.schedule(secsFromNow + ' seconds', 'sayHello');
```

Comment: So, by default the job will be run at 12 am in that day?

Comment: Your code above is worked for me. But how do tell  Agenda to run a job in 1 Jan 2018 at 4 pm. You got idea ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to run at particular time then set the time in `futureDate` and calculate minutes for the day like `var oneDay_ms = 60 * 24` and schedule it with `agenda.schedule(daysFromNow + ' minutes', 'sayHello');`

Comment: Let me update the answer for the time `1 Jan 2018 at 4 pm`

Comment: Ok.As your wish

Comment: I have updated the answer by calculating the seconds to let it run sharply at 4pm

Comment: Good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### With Agenda.js

[interval can be a human-readable format String, a cron format String, or a Number.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda/v/4.0.1#creating-jobs)

meaning it supports **cron-style scheduling method**.

#### for example

> you could schedule a job to run 3 minutes from the current time

```
  await agenda.schedule('3 minutes', 'send confirmation to new user', {email:"newuser@mal.com"} );

  // Alternatively, you could also do:
  await agenda.schedule('*/3 * * * *', 'send confirmation to new user', {email:"newuser@mal.com"});
```

> run a job Monday at 09:00

```
   await agenda.schedule('0 9 * * 1', 'MondayJob', {msg:"guess what today is 'Monday'"});
```

> run on Saturday at 23:45 (11:45 PM)

```
await agenda.schedule('45 23 * * 6', 'jobName', {});
```