# Run function at certain time based on time value in MongoDB record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server

So I have a NodeJS backend and using MongoDB as the DB. I want to run a certain function every time the current time equals a certain value of time as mentioned in the DB object.

For example:-

I have a record in the DB with the timestamp of `1623263299944`, and there is a certain function named `cancelIntent` which performs some kind of task, now I want to call this function when the current time equals the mentioned time in the DB record.

How can I achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You need a scheduler. Something like a cron on nix systems or a task scheduler on windows. Databases don't run functions, they store data.

Comment: Will this timestamp ever change? If it won't, task scheduler, etc. is the way to go

Comment: Thank you for your response @AlexBlex, are you talking about something like running some corn jobs at a certain interval?

Comment: Thank you @MilesZew for your response, you are right, it won't change. Could you please share some links to blogs or so, so that I can get a better understanding of how to implement with the tech stack I am using?

Comment: I pointed you to some resources, but let me know if you need anymore help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search came up with [this blog post](https://www.codementor.io/@miguelkouam/how-to-schedule-tasks-in-node-js-express-using-agenda-h8sdo6b9p), for [this library](https://github.com/agenda/agenda), which looks like what you're looking for

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226352/how-do-i-run-cron-like-job-at-certain-date-time-in-the-future-using-agenda-in-no) that looks like it gives you what you're looking for

It looks like you just need to calculate how many days, hours, minuets, etc. in the future you want to schedule your task, and then input that into the `agenda.schedule` function

Alternatively you could use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), which has the benefit of allowing you to input a date directly, like this:

```js
const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  /* your code */
})
```

I quickly tested this and it seems to work without issues

Comment: Thank you @MilesZew for the detailed solution, I will have a look on this for sure :)